# Turn animated gif into WhatsApp sendable video

Tags: video, whatsapp-messenger, media-files

I'd like to convert a short gif-animation to a video so I can send it to a friend via WhatsApp. Do you know easy ways to accomplish that (e.g. codec etc.)? Best would be doing it on the device directly but I could do it as well on a computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this online tool to convert it: http://www.giftovideo.com/

Regarding tools, you could use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) + [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but it's kind of tricky finding the correct options. There is some instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212821/animated-gif-to-avi-on-linux). I tried but some of the cases didn't work.

Comment: As a side note regarding the online tool, at this exactly time, they seem to be facing some performance problem, for every time you try it, you're going to end up in a queue like forever.

Comment: Nowadays FFMPEG can do it without imagemagick: `ffmpeg -i input.gif output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with a solution that you can use on a PC, then SuperUser.com has this: 
[How do I convert an animated GIF to a YouTube friendly video format?](https://superuser.com/q/5730/4825)

For an on-Android solution, none of the video coverters specifically mention this but as the ffmpeg library does support this (as seen in the [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/8794/4825)), apps like [Video Converter Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=roman10.media.converter&hl=en) or [Media Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AndroidA.MediaConverter) and [so on](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ffmpeg&c=apps), being ffmpeg based, should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the extension from .gif to .mp4 in your device and forward to anyone. Only thing is that  the recipient needs to open it in gallery to see the animation.

Comment: Doesn't work in my system. Can you detail the steps for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on Android 5.0.1:

1. Install this app: [Convert GIF to Video & Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.parizene.gif2video&hl=en)
2. Open the app and select the GIF you want to convert.
3. Choose 3gpp video codec.
4. Tap the convert button.
5. Done. Now you can send the video through WhatsApp.